# Что делать, когда спрашивающий продолжает бессмысленно менять и портить свои вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, правки

Спрашивающий намеренно продолжает бессмысленно менять свои вопросы (а местами и портить). Я правки откатил, в комментариях везде отписался, но изменение вопросов продолжается. Что с этим делать?

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465442
- [Как создать файл (размер: 0 байт), при удалении которого освободится 100МБ на диске?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465441)
- [Создание разреженного файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465965)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465446
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465966

Comment: На самом деле это все хорошие, грамотные вопросы (у меня даже сложилось впечатление, что кто-то пытается так определить компетентность отвечающих на сайте (и многие эту проверку не прошли)). Зачем их закрывать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создать тревогу (флаг) для привлечения внимания модератора. Он может применить ограничения на правки как к вопросу ("спор по содержанию текста"), так и к автору правок (баны на любой вкус и цвет).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть при обнаружении такой тенденции - отметить флагом все что пострадало? (в данном случае, например, все 5 вопросов?)

Comment: @KromStern да, именно так. Лучше все вопросы, чем какой-то один, это облегчит модератору его работу.

Comment: Все верно. Вопросы залочены, участник уведомлен.

Comment: @Nofate: сделал скриншоты )

Comment: Не нравится мне эта формулировка "заблокирована успокоиться"

Comment: @Nofate: да, так себе. Какие там вообще есть, можете полный список заскриншотить?

Comment: Выбора причины бана нет как такового.

Comment: @Nofate: но я обычно вижу "успокоиться". Это вы сами каждый раз пишете или это предлагаемый вариант?

Comment: Полагаю, причина константна

Comment: @Nofate: [Перевод получше для "заблокирована успокоиться"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1850)